# NamedPipeClientStream does not connect

Tags: c#, vb.net, named-pipes

In our main application we have the following function (in VB.Net):

```
 Public Overrides Function GetNewResults(setToProcessed As Boolean) As List(Of ReceivedData)

    Dim client = New NamedPipeClientStream(".", "PipesOfPiece",
                                           PipeDirection.InOut, PipeOptions.None,
                                           TokenImpersonationLevel.Impersonation)
    client.Connect()
    Dim reader = New StreamReader(client)
    Dim writer = New StreamWriter(client)
    writer.AutoFlush = True

    writer.WriteLine(DbPath)

    Dim serialized = reader.ReadLine
    client.Close()

    Dim newResults = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of List(Of ReceivedData))(serialized)

    Return newResults

End Function
```

The NamedPipeServer has been written in C# and, for now, is hosted in a console application:

```
 static void StartServer()
    {

        server = new NamedPipeServerStream("PipesOfPiece", direction: PipeDirection.InOut,maxNumberOfServerInstances:10);

        server.WaitForConnection();
        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server);
        StreamWriter writer=  new StreamWriter(server);
        writer.AutoFlush = true;

        while (true)
            {
                var dbPath = reader.ReadLine();
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbPath)) continue;
                if (!File.Exists(dbPath))
                {
                    writer.WriteLine($"{dbPath} does not exist.");
                    continue;
                }
                var communicator = new DapperBwsCommunicator(dbPath,provider: "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0");
                var newResults = communicator.GetAllResults(setToProcessed: true);
                var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newResults);
                writer.WriteLine(serialized);
            }
    }
```

The `GetNewResults` function is called every three seconds. The first time this function is called it works correctly. But the second time the code blocks on  `Client.Connect`. It seems then that the server does not respond any more.

Where am I going wrong?

*EDIT*
Thanks to Fandango's answer I came with a different implementation. This seems to work:

```
static void StartServer()
{

    server = new NamedPipeServerStream("PipesOfPiece", direction: PipeDirection.InOut,maxNumberOfServerInstances:10);

    server.WaitForConnection();
    StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(server);
    StreamWriter writer=  new StreamWriter(server);
    writer.AutoFlush = true;

    while (true)
        {
            var dbPath = reader.ReadLine();
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dbPath)) continue;
            if (!File.Exists(dbPath))
            {
                writer.WriteLine($"{dbPath} does not exist.");
                continue;
            }
            var communicator = new DapperBwsCommunicator(dbPath,provider: "Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0");
            var newResults = communicator.GetAllResults(setToProcessed: true);
            var serialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(newResults);
            writer.WriteLine(serialized);
            server.Disconnnect();
            server.WaitForConnection();
        }
}
```

Comment: You should have a single `WaitForConnection()`, inside the `while (true)` loop, on top of it. The code inside the loop should be wrapped in a `try/catch/finally` block. In the finally section, flush the current `reader` Stream (no matter what `AutoFlush` is set to) and call `server.Disconnnect();`. Outside the loop, the server and the Stream must be disposed of (e.g., `server?.Dispose();` etc.). There's also no way to exit the loop at this time, except closing the app (I understand that it might not matter much in a Console application, but...). (A `PipeSecurity` option is missing completely)

Comment: Of course, the `server` and the Streams objects are created outside the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this happens because you keep creating a new client connection every 3 seconds, while on the server side, after the first WaitForConnection, the code is stuck inside the loop and not waiting for client connections anymore.